# How to append minutes of a day into a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I know how to append an item in to a list:

```
minutes = []

minutes.append('08:30')
```

my question is,how to loop all the minutes during 8:30am to 15:00,and append them in a list?

```
format like minutes = ['08:30','08:31',...,15:30]
```

or maybe every 10 minutes like

```
minutes = ['08:30','08:40',...,'15:30']
```

Any friend can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
import pandas as pd
time_list = []
for time in pd.date_range('8:30','15:00', freq='1min').time:
    time_list.append(time.strftime('%H:%M'))
print(time_list)
```

Output:

```
['08:30', '08:31', '08:32', '08:33', ... , '14:57', '14:58', '14:59', '15:00']
```

More succinctly:

```
>>> pd.date_range('8:30','15:00', freq='1min'
                 ).format(formatter=lambda x:x.strftime('%H:%M'))

['08:30', '08:31', '08:32', '08:33', ... , '14:57', '14:58', '14:59', '15:00']
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will give you an array of string representations of each of the minutes from `08:30` to `15:00`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start = datetime.strptime('08:30', '%H:%M')
end = datetime.strptime('15:00', '%H:%M')
delta = timedelta(minutes = 1)
times = []
while start <= end:
    times.append(start.strftime('%H:%M'))
    start += delta
print(times)
```

Output:

```
['08:30', '08:31', '08:32', '08:33', ... , '14:57', '14:58', '14:59', '15:00']
```

You can get times every 10 minutes by changing the `minutes` value in `delta = timedelta(minutes = 1)` to `10`.